# Understanding Inheritance vs Composition in golang

Tags: go, inheritance, composition

Coming from Java background, I am unable to understand how inheritance can be achieved using Composition or How composition solves some of the common solutions achieved by Inheritance?

```
interface ICommand {
    void Save(Records data)
    Records LoadRecords()
    Info GetInfo()
}

abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand {
    Records LoadRecords()  {
        var info = GetInfo()
        //implement common method.
    }
}

class CommandABC : BaseCommand {
    Info GetInfo(){
        return info;
    }

    void Save(Records data){
        // implement
    }
}

c = new CommandABC();
c.LoadRecords(); // BaseCommand.LoadRecords -> CommandABC.Info -> Return records
c.Save(); //Command ABC.Save
```

I want to achieve the same functionality in Go using composition.
After all this is fair design and should be good to implement in Go.

```
type ICommand interface {
    void Save(data Records)
    LoadRecords() Records
    GetInfo() Info
}

type BaseCommand struct {
    ICommand  //no explicit inheritance. Using composition
}

func(c BaseCommand) LoadRecords() {
    info := c.GetInfo()
    //implement common method
}

type CommandABC struct {
    BaseCommand //Composition is bad choice here?
}

func(c CommandABC) Save(data Records) {
    //implement
}

func(c CommandABC) GetInfo() Info {
    //implement
}

func main(){
    c := CommandABC{}
    c.LoadRecords(); // BaseCommand.LoadRecords -> fails to call GetInfo since ICommand is nil
    c.Save(); //Command ABC.Save
}
```

It can be made to work out like this

```
func main(){
    c := CommandABC{}
    c.ICommand = c //so akward. don't even understand why I am doing this
    c.LoadRecords(); // BaseCommand.LoadRecords -> fails to call GetInfo since ICommand is nil
    c.Save(); //Command ABC.Save
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me on achieving such functionality from Go design perspective.

My concerns/queries more around understanding, how to use composition for such problems/code reusability with better design patterns going forward.

Comment: Composition and Inheritance can both be used for code reuse, however they are not the same. Also Composition is not something to be used to implement Inheritance. Do not try to mimic inheritance in Go.

Comment: @mkopriva while i agree with you completely, all top google search results suggest using "composition" to achieve the same. Thats where my question started, how to achieve such functionality in golang. Any design patterns to achieve it. Whats the core design principle should be used to drive better design for such scenarios

Comment: In Go interfaces are implemented *implicitly*, the `BaseCommand struct { ICommand }` is not what you're looking for here. You can declare the interface, declare the consumers of the interface, declare concrete implementations of the interface and pass them to the consumers. You can use embedding to reuse common or default implentations of methods. That's about it.

Comment: @mkopriva please explain fully with above example. sorry for my bad understanding

Comment: Basically this `func(c BaseCommand) LoadRecords() { info := c.GetInfo() }`, where `c.GetInfo()` executes the `CommandABC`'s `GetInfo` method is not possible without the awkwardness. You need to ditch the inheritance mindset and come up with a different approach how to reuse the logic of `LoadRecords`.

Comment: Does this help make things clearer? https://play.golang.com/p/_-yg-pZ4QbV

Comment: @mkopriva for clear demonstration. Any help in better design solutions specific to golang or I should rephrase it as thinking in go better

Comment: In Go the main way to reuse code is by providing _functions_. Functions and methods taking interface values can be used with different types. Composition vs. Inheritance is just a design shift. You can use composition also in Java (and it often leads to less brittle code than using inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it a few different ways, but the most idiomatic is probably something along these lines. It's hard to give a detailed answer based on a contrived example with no details and most code elided, but I think this gets to where you're trying to go.

```
type Infoer interface {
   GetInfo() Info
}

func LoadRecords(i Infoer) Records  {
    var info = i.GetInfo()
    //implement common method.
}

type CommandABC struct {
    info Info
}

func (c CommandABC) GetInfo() Info {
    return c.info;
}

func (CommandABC) Save(data Records){
    // implement
}

c := CommandABC{};
records := LoadRecords(c);
c.Save(records);
```

Comment: The Info type/struct is not defined anywhere. But it is used as result of GetInfo(). Even when this is not the focus point here, it should be there imo, to not confuse ppls.

Comment: The body of `Infoer` interface is not clear to me. What does `Info GetInfo()` inside the interface mean? Do you mean `GetInfo() Info`?

Comment: @AmitTendulkar yes that was a typo, I've corrected it now